# Immutable classes with calculated fields

Tags: dart, constructor, immutability

To initialize a final variable using logic that can’t be handled in the initializer list you can use a factory constructor. Even though that logic is a simple math operation, it apparently breaks Dart's `const` contract.

I am failing to find a way to use such an alternative constructor, i.e. allowing me to pass three points instead of the center and radius, while still keeping the immutability of the final object.

```
import 'dart:math';

class Circle {
  final Point center;
  final double radius;

  const Circle(this.center, this.radius);

  factory Circle.fromPoints(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    Point center = _getCenter(p1, p2, p3);
    return Circle(center, center.distanceTo(p1));
  }

  static Point _getCenter(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3) {
    double centerX = ...
    double centerY = ...

    return Point(centerX, centerY);
  }
```

I've also tried making that `getCenter` method public and calculating the center outside the constructor, but it again fails to compile as the calculated center is determined to be `Null` in the stage of initialization.

```
Point p1 = const Point(-1, 0);
Point p2 = const Point(0, 1);
Point p3 = const Point(1, 0);
  
Point center = Circle.getCenter(p1, p2, p2);
Circle circle = const Circle(center, center.distanceTo(p1));
```

But I still prefer having multiple constructors producing const objects instead of such workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an *immutable* result, but not a *constant* one.

The restrictions on constant evaluation are such that you are not allowed to call any but a select few functions in `const` expressions (mainly operators on numbers). You can't even extract the `x` and `y` positions of a `Point` during constant evaluation. If you need more than what constant evaluation allows, you cannot do the computation as a constant expression. You also cannot pass non-constant values into a `const` constructor invocations.

That doesn't mean that the result isn't immutable. It's still a class with a two final values, each holding immutable values.

So, what you are doing is fine, and correct, except for putting `const` in front of `Circle(center, center.distanceTo(p1))`, because the second argument is not a constant expression.